# Is removeable media always mounted to the same path

Tags: mount, sd-card

I have and SD card that I want to use to save youtube films on. My laptop has an integrated SD card slot, will this always be mounted to the same path? If remove the card attach a  USB drive then insert my card again, will a short cut to it still work? Will it always be the same?

If not, is it possible to always mount it to the same path?

Comment: If you label the media and give it a name, it will mount it with that name.  Use `gparted` to name your partition.  It has to be unmounted.  Just right-click in gparted and select `Label` to name it.  Now it should always mount under `/media/username/labelname`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It uses the label name for the partition, or the partition's unique ID if no label exists, for the mounted directory. So it will generally always be mounted in the same directory, unless you attempt to mount multiple devices simultaneously which all have the same label.

If you try to mount multiple partitions with the same label, then the first one should get the label for the directory, and additional mounts will be on different paths with modified names.

Comment: and if 2 sd-cards are labeled the same name? >:-)

Comment: Then you can't mount them at the same time. They will be mounted in the same location. :)

Comment: then that would be a no to the question for that case ;-)

Comment: If they have the same name, one of them will be appended with the number 1 at the end.  I have two drives labelled "Storage" and that's what happens with mine.

Comment: @Rinzwind That would be a no to your question, but that is not what the original poster was asking. :)

Comment: @dobey Are you sure about the same name thing? As I tested that, if two partitions have same name, the last one will be mounted with an added `_` after their name